# Accessing an Obj-C property from a C++ function (iOS)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, core-audio

I'm writing an iOS application that does some audio processing in the AppDelegate using the Core Audio API. I have a `@property` in my AppDelegate that gets updated in the ViewController, and this `@property` needs to be accessed in my render callback function, which is written in C++. I discovered, to my chagrin, that you can't access an Obj-C `@property` in a C++ function by simply using `_propertyName` as you would in an Obj-C method, so now I'm wondering how to go about doing that.

Here is my `@property`, in AppDelegate.h:

`@property float centerFreq`

Here is my render callback function, in AppDelegate.m:

```
static OSStatus audioProcessingRenderCallback (
                                               void *                           inRefCon,
                                               AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
                                               const AudioTimeStamp *           inTimeStamp,
                                               UInt32                           inBusNumber,
                                               UInt32                           inNumberFrames,
                                               AudioBufferList *                ioData
                                               ) {
    //audio processing stuff that needs to access _centerFreq
}
```

My first thought was to just make `audioProcessingRenderCallback` an Objective-C method, but this causes an error when I try to set that as the callback function with this code:

```
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = audioProcessingRenderCallback;
```

What would be the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you rename your C++ file to .mm?  Then it will compile as Objective-C++ and you can access it as you would in a .m file.  Not an answer because I'm not addressing your "how to access the value" question, but you might find this approach useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't appear to change anything with how my C++ functions treat `@property`s. They're still not recognized when I try to access them from within a C++ function.

Comment: Once you change the C++ file extension to .mm, include ViewController.h from the C++ file. Put a method on your ViewController like -(ViewController*) getInstance; Return the instance (or make it accessible via some other mechanism) to the C++ file.  Then in the C++ (.mm) file, you can just call instance.centerFreq = 1.0;  However, be mindful that you only do this on the main thread.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, as I described in my comment to your post, is to change the extension on your C++ file.  Make the extension .mm (i.e. AudioProcessor.mm).  This enables Objective-C++, and you can then just pass your object around and make calls on it from the C++ file.  This is probably easiest.

If you can't change the extension of the C++ file, then you need to make a bridge function.

In your ViewController (.m file), make a C function like so:

```
void updateCenterFreq( float value ) {
    myViewControllerInstance.centerFreq = value;
}
```

Obviously you have to find a way to make the ViewController instance visible to the C function.  One way is to assign a static pointer in your .m file.  Only useful if you have one instance and you're not worrying about threads, but that may work for you.  If you have more than one instance of the view controller you have to find a way to locate the instance.  How to do that is beyond the scope of my answer here.  I will amend this to say though that if you plan to call updateCenterFreq() on a non-main thread, then you need to use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to get on the main thread before you set centerFreq (I'm assuming since it's in a view controller you're planning to update UI, which *must* be done on the main thread).

Now in your AudioProcessor.h file (the C++ file's header) do:

```
extern "C" {
    void updateCenterFreq( float value );
}
```

Then you can call updateCenterFreq() when you need to.

Again, this doesn't consider thread safety, or how you locate your instance, but this is how you can do it.

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, changing the file from .m to .mm didn't appear to have any effect on my ability to access properties from C++ code.

As for your other suggestion, I'm a little confused. centerFreq is a property of AppDelegate, not ViewController. However, I have some stuff in the ViewController that I want to be able to update centerFreq, so what I have right now is:

`appDel = ((PWAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);`
`appDel.centerFreq = [self updateFreq:param1 withPar:param2];`

Comment: oof, sorry about the nasty code formatting in the comment.

Comment: Sorry.  Replace everywhere I said "View Controller" with "App Delegate."  The point, if you're not using a .mm file, is to make a pure C function accessor in your AppDelegate .m file, then declare that function as extern "C" in your C++ file, then call it from the C++ file.  The pure C function in the .m file can call Objective-C functions.  Similarly, if you rename the .cpp file .mm, you can call all Objective-C functions natively, so long as you include the proper headers in your C++ file.

Comment: Rename your .cpp file to .mm, and then in it `#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` and `#include "PWAppDelegate.h"`.  Then you can do `((PWAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).centerFreq = 1.0;`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear. `((PWAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).centerFreq = 1.0;` is in my ViewController.mm and it (seemingly) works just fine. There is no .cpp file, but I'm writing C++ code in my AppDelegate.m, from which I am trying to access the centerFreq property declared in AppDelegate.h. So as it stands, centerFreq SHOULD be getting updated by the line in ViewController- but I can't access it in AppDelegate.m to find out. Does that make more sense? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: How are you writing C++ code in AppDelegate.m?  The extension .m will explicitly not enable the C++ compiler for that file (unless you've overridden it, but don't do that).

Comment: In `audioProcessingRenderCallback()` just do the same thing you do in your view controller: call `((PWAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).centerFreq = 1.0;` (provided `audioProcessingRenderCallback()` is being called on the main thread).

Comment: I may write a completely different answer once we get this sorted out ;)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that you can't access the property with underscore member notation (e.g. `instance._centerFreq`) in `audioProcessingRenderCallback()` because it is a private class member of the AppDelegate.  But you *can* access it via dot notation (e.g. `instance.centerFreq`) because that way of accessing it is really calling methods on the app delegate instance (the getter and setter functions), which are public.

Comment: Oooops. I guess it's just C. There were some things I was doing that I thought were C++ things, but apparently are in C as well. (I'm not very experienced with C, as you might be able to tell! Ha.) 

Hmmm...grabbing an instance of the appDelegate using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] seems to stop everything from yelling, but why is that different from just using self?

Comment: `self` is only available in member functions of an objective c instance.  `audioProcessingRenderCallback()` is not a member function.

Comment: Aha! Well, that seems to have settled it. Many thanks for your patience. I appreciate the help.

Comment: my c++ function inside mm file

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, to pass reference of `centerFreq` to your method:

```
static OSStatus audioProcessingRenderCallback (
                                               float *                          centerFrequency,
                                               void *                           inRefCon,
                                               AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
                                               const AudioTimeStamp *           inTimeStamp,
                                               UInt32                           inBusNumber,
                                               UInt32                           inNumberFrames,
                                               AudioBufferList *                ioData
                                               ) {
    //audio processing stuff that needs to access _centerFreq
}
```

then do what you wanna do on that reference, and updates will reflect in your property.

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  centerFreq should be considered a private class member and its setter may be overridden or have side effects that this would totally bypass.

Comment: +1 Point taken, **Please refer par's comment before using above answer**.